# Discord.js, battle bot editing the message takes too much time

Tags: node.js, async-await, discord.js, setinterval

I am making a battle bot using discordjs and I'm having some difficulties in updating the message according to the logs that my bot created for the battle. Here's the current code I'm using.

```js
let interval = setInterval(async () => {
    if(turnCounter <= battle.logs.length){
        let currPlayer = turnCounter % 2 === 0 ? p1 : p2;
        embed
          .setTitle(("Round ", turnCounter))
          .setDescription(`
          **Round Summary** \n
          ${currPlayer.toString()} used **${battle.textlogs[turnCounter][turnCounter % 2][0].name}** and \ndealt **${battle.textlogs[turnCounter][turnCounter % 2][0].damage}** \nand \nhealed **${battle.textlogs[turnCounter][turnCounter % 2][0].heal}**!`);
        embed.fields[0] = {name: "Player 1", value: `${message.author.username} \n Class: ${battle.player1.class.name} \n HP: **${battle.health_log[turnCounter][0]}** (${battle.health_log[turnCounter][0] - battle.health_log[turnCounter-1 >= 0 ? turnCounter-1 : 0][0]})`, inline: true};
        embed.fields[1] = {name: "Player 2", value: `${user.username} \n Class: ${battle.player2.class.name} \n HP: **${battle.health_log[turnCounter][1]}** (${battle.health_log[turnCounter][1] - battle.health_log[turnCounter-1 >= 0 ? turnCounter-1 : 0][1]})`, inline: true};
        let t = Date.now();
        m = await m.edit(embed);
        console.log(`It took ${Date.now()-t}ms for request to travel!`);
        turnCounter++;
    }
    else clearInterval(interval);
}, 1000);
```

This approach resulted in the following log:

```
It took 179ms for request to travel!
It took 1879ms for request to travel!
It took 1045ms for request to travel!
It took 197ms for request to travel!
```

There are two problems that I'm facing here.

1 ) I'm waiting 1000ms to perform the code and awaiting message update takes 200-2000ms. It's too much. I want it to be around 200ms all time. Total of 1000+200ms is pretty okay. How should I deal with this?

2 ) When there are many concurrent battles happening, they all wait each other's `await` to continue execution. If I'm supposed to await these messages, I need to use clusters to fork the process but when I fork, multiple discordjs instances open up and bot connects to discord for several times and responds to commands several times too. How am I supposed to handle this problem?

My attempts:

- Current one
- While loop
  I tried to make in a while loop instead of setInterval however it behaved the same.
- Not awaiting
  I tried `m = m.edit(embed)` instead of `m = await m.edit(embed)`, this time it suddenly ended the battle and sent the last battle log to the discord.

Comment: You can't edit a message that frequently, it's API spam. The reason why there's a delay is because the Discord API is ratelimiting you.

Comment: I thought that at first too, however Yggdrasil bot can update it's message that frequently. [ygg.fun](https://ygg.fun/) you can check out Yggdrasil's Death Battle feature.

Comment: Some bots, if popular enough (Dank Memer, MEE6 for example), are granted special API permissions which allows them to make much more frequent API calls. Last time I was aware, a bot has to be in around 1 million servers to be granted this. That is probably the case with Yggdrasil.